# SQL: How to self join?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I don't know if this could be achieved using self join. But i tried doing so. I have table like below:

```
storeid levelid modelid classid value1  value2
101     1       34       23      245    246
101     2       34       23      112    229
102     1       34       23      369    226
102     2       34       23      869    245
103     1       34       23      111    102
103     2       34       23      545    985
```

So i want to select from this table such that storeid is selected distinctly and for unique combination of levelid,modelid,classid: value1 and value2 are assigned horizontal. What i mean is like on below structure:

```
storeid value1  value2  value1  value2
101      245    246       112    119
102      369    226       869    245
103      111    102       545    985
```

I have only come of with self join idea but what i have done is not near to the solution. If not the solution helpful idea will also be much appreciated. Below is query for test:

```
create table  #tblTest
(
  storeid int,
  levelid int,
  modelid int,
  classid int,
  value1 int,
  value2 int,
)
insert into #tblTest (storeid,levelid,modelid,classid,value1,value2) values(101,1,34,23,245,246)
insert into #tblTest (storeid,levelid,modelid,classid,value1,value2) values(101,2,34,23,225,229)
insert into #tblTest (storeid,levelid,modelid,classid,value1,value2) values(102,1,34,23,245,226)
insert into #tblTest (storeid,levelid,modelid,classid,value1,value2) values(102,2,34,23,245,245)
insert into #tblTest (storeid,levelid,modelid,classid,value1,value2) values(103,1,34,23,245,102)
insert into #tblTest (storeid,levelid,modelid,classid,value1,value2) values(103,2,34,23,45,985)
```

If i am not able to present my problem, Please let me know.

Thank You.

Comment: 1 StoreId has only 2 levels or more?

Comment: stores could have more then two levels @TriV

Comment: Ok i think you need a dynamic sql with pivot. Try to search it.

Comment: yes i thought about that too. But pivot is use to change row to column right? But i think it is not suitable  in my case.

Comment: Or multi self joins, you could do it dynamically..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a self join if you like:

```
select t1.storeid, t1.value1, t1.value2, t2.value1, t2.value2
from #tbltest t1 join
     #tbltest t2
     on t1.storedid = t2.storedid and
        t1.levelid = 1 and t2.levelid = 2;
```

In your example data, `modelid` and `classid` are not needed.  Buy you can add equality conditions for them as well.

Comment: Thank You for your quick response. Your solution give the desire output but levelid is not always 1 or 2. Level id could have other values too.

Comment: If it is a multi-level table do you expect 2 new columns of output for each level? is there a maximum number of levels? These are facts needed to give an answer. Amend you question - do not rely on comments to make the question complete.

Comment: Thank you for your concern. I am going to do it from front end to generate dynamic query.

Comment: @Amir . . . You should ask *another* question and provide appropriate sample data and explain exactly what you want to do.