# Grouping by a column to compare values between similar rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to turn this

```
+----+---------+-------------------+-----------+
| id | year    | desc              | amount    |
+----+---------+-------------------+-----------+
|  1 | 2017    | car               | 500       |
|  2 | 2017    | car               | 550       |
|  1 | 2018    | car               | 490       |
|  2 | 2018    | car               | 550       |
|  1 | 2017    | house             | 200       |
|  2 | 2017    | house             | 300       |
|  1 | 2018    | house             | 210       |
|  2 | 2018    | house             | 320       |
|  1 | 2019    | house             | 290       |
|  2 | 2019    | house             | 325       |
+----+---------+-------------------+-----------+
```

Into something like this

```
+----+---------+---------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+
| id | year_0  | year_1  | desc              | amount_0  | amount_1  |
+----+---------+---------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 | 2017    | 2018    | car               | 500       | 490       |
|  2 | 2017    | 2018    | car               | 550       | 550       |
|  1 | 2017    | 2018    | house             | 200       | 210       |
|  2 | 2017    | 2018    | house             | 300       | 320       |
+----+---------+---------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

But I'm having difficulty getting the two years and two amounts to group by description.

Comment: And there will never be more than 2 years? Google "pivot sql server".

Comment: You could also take advantage of a [self join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43859882/sql-how-to-self-join).

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592),
and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166)
(ignore if you're not asking about hw).
Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),
and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: why house 2019 is not in the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the result by applying `join`:

```
SELECT A.id,a.year year_0,b.year year_1, A.[desc], A.amount amount_0,B.amount amount_1 
FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE Year= Datepart(year,GETDATE())-1) AS A
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE Year= Datepart(year,GETDATE())) AS B
ON A.id=B.id AND A.[desc]=B.[desc]
```